# ModalBox display only once sitewide

Tags: javascript, popup, modal-dialog

I am using the script called ModalBox. I want to display the ModalBox on page load the first time a visitor reaches my site. Every time after the first visit the modalbox should not display again. How can I do this?

I have set up a testing page. Please Visit this page to view my code.
[Testing Site](http://www.slingerlandweb.com/modalbox)

The code that I am using to pop up the ModalBox on page load is:

> body onLoad="Modalbox.show('pages/modalbox_page.html', {width: 460, title: 'Sending status'}); return false;"

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need a mechanism to persist the fact that a user has visited your site, the best available mechanism for this is to use a cookie - if there's no cookie (or no flag in the cookie data) then the user hasn't been here before so you need to show the dialog *and set the cookie*.

This mechanism isn't perfect, it can only log that the current user of a specific machine using the current browser is visiting for the first time and it also depends on the user/system accepting persistent cookies which not all do - but it is the mechanism you need to use to do the job.